# chmod symbolic notation: unexpected "=" operation behavior

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, chmod, gnu

I am reading `The Linux Command Line` by `William Shotts` and I read somewhere in the book a part regarding permissions which says `The operation may be a “+” indicating that a permission is to be added, a “-” indicating that a permission is to be taken away, *or a “=” indicating that only the specified permissions are to be applied and that all others are to be removed*.`(see the part between `**`)

So I tried it:

```
me@ubuntu:~$ > foo
me@ubuntu:~$ ls -al | grep foo
-rw-rw-r--  1 me me     0 Apr  2 05:17 foo
me@ubuntu:~$ chmod g=x foo 
me@ubuntu:~$ ls -al | grep foo
-rw---xr--  1 me me     0 Apr  2 05:17 foo
iuliu@ubuntu:~$
```

Now the file is created with `-rw-rw-r--` rights assigned and after I execute `chmod g=x foo` I expect them to be `------x---` (only the group to have execution rights and nothing more). I understand that to have execution permission you have to have read permission, so the read permission for the group is needed, but why does the user permissions are still `rw`?

Thanks!

Comment: `ls -al | grep foo`???  Why don’t you just say `ls -l foo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build upon and/or clarify Davidw’s answer:  Since you’re saying `g=`,
you are asking for only the group permissions to be changed. 
If you would say `chmod =x foo`, you would get `---x--x--x`. 
If you want to get `------x---`, do

```
chmod =,g=x foo
```

This is the same as

```
chmod  =  foo
chmod g=x foo
```

The first command sets the permissions to 0 (`----------`),
because it sets all three user groups (`u`, `g`, and `o`) to **no access**,
and I guess by now you understand what the second one does. 
As indicated, you can concatenate operations by separating them with commas.

> I understand that to have execution permission you have to have read permission,
>   so the read permission for the group is needed, …

This is true only if you’re talking about a script. 
A (compiled) binary executable can be run with only execute permission.

Answer (score 1):

g=x adds the execute permission to the group, without changing the other permissions. It only affects the specified portion of the permissions, when you choose a specific part of the permissions. If you use chmod with the numbers, for example, chmod 777, that will overwrite all of the current permissions.

Comment: Yes, 777 overwrites all the current permissions because it explicitly sets all permissions. But what I'm doing here its leaving some of the permissions untouched (e.g. user permissions). According to the text, it should set these permissions to 0 because *all others (i.e. permissions) are to be removed*. Isn't this true?

Comment: `chmod 777`: nonononono! Never ever run `chmod 777`. It is practically never required! Not even for "testing purposes". If the file is readable, then it's readable. If it's writable by the `user` or `group` that need to write to it, then it's writable. There is absolutely zero need to give everyone write permissions, and forgetting to `chmod` it back to something sane is exactly how multinationals get hacked. Just don't do it. Ever. I wrote [an introduction of Unix permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35895436/660921). Please read it!